# ASP .NET MVC4 web application with mobile views not loading mobile css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC4 web application. I want to create views that is spesific for mobile browsers. I have followed this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features. I have installed the package jQuery.Mobile.MVC and added the requested line to the Global.asax file. The installation have created a file called _Layout.Mobile.cshtml, and this file looks like this:

**_Layout.Mobile.cshtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css", "~/Content/jquerymobile/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
<body> 

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        @Html.Partial("_ViewSwitcher")

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            @RenderSection("featured", false)
            @RenderBody()       
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also added a mobile view for the index view.

**Index.Mobile.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}


<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
```

But when I open the webpage in an iPhone simulator, the page looks nothing like the one in the tutorial. It is blank with plain text. I have viewed the page source and can see that only the site.Mobile.css file is loaded.

```
<head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Home</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/Site.Mobile.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

I created a new web application project through VS2012, but this time I chose the Mobile Application template. When I run this project and view the page source, a lot more css-files is displaying.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Log in</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="/Content/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    </head>
```

I have checked that all of these files exists in my webApp project, but for some reason they are not loading. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure this out, but the solution was a tricky one so I'm answering my own question in case others experience the same problem.
I changed the App_Start/BundleMobileConfig.cs from:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jquerymobile/css").Include(
            "~/Content/jquery.mobile-{version}.css"
            ));
```

to

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jquerymobile/css").Include(
            "~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css",
            "~/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css",
            "~/Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css"
            ));
```

It looks like I only got the minified version of the jquery mobile css, while the stylebundle was looking for the original version. I think this is a bug when installing the jquery.mobile.MVC package.